# how to get the last added image file from gallery without using "Media.openPhotoGallery" in titanium?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

In my app i need to display the last added image in the gallery every time the app loads. I was able to do it with the images from applicationDataDirectory but thats not my requirement. I need it from the whole gallery images. How do i do it. Thanks in advance.

```
 var dir = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory);

 var fdir = dir.getDirectoryListing();

 var numPhotos = fdir.length || 1;

 for(var a=0; a < fdir.length; a++ ) {
    Ti.API.info("inside for");
    Ti.API.info("filename"+fdir[a]);
    var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,fdir[a]);         
    if(f.exists()){
        var fr = f.read();
        Ti.API.info("fr.mimeType"+fr.mimeType);
        if(fr.mimeType === 'image/jpeg'){
            Ti.API.info('photo.nativePath: ' + f.nativePath);
            imagePath = f.nativePath;
            break;           
            }           
        }                       
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by _I need it from the whole gallery images_? From the device photo gallery?

Comment: images saved to gallery by other apps too

Comment: The Titanium API only has an [API](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media-method-openPhotoGallery) to have the user select a single photo from the device photo gallery. There's some modules like [qs.urbanimage.library](http://gitt.io/component/qs.urbanimage.library) that might get you more.

Comment: thanks for your help @Fokke-Appcelerator much obliged. this is the module for ios right. can i have a module for android too?

Comment: Let me Google that for you: http://gitt.io/search?q=photo+gallery 

Answer (score -3):

I think the below code works....for you

```
String[] projection = new String[]{
MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE
};
final Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
    .query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, 
           null, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");

// Put it in the image view
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pictureView);
String imageLocation = cursor.getString(1);
File imageFile = new File(imageLocation);
if (imageFile.exists()) {   // TODO: is there a better way to do this?
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);         
}
}
```

Comment: i need to do it with titanium sdk. it seems like the code for android.